# Elasticsearch Query DSL: optimize result contents

Tags: querydsl, elasticsearch

In my dataset, which has some 6 fields, I wrote the following query to get the fields that I require:

```
{    
       "size" : 40000,
        "query" :  {
             "match_all" : {}
        },
       "fields" : ["icao", "city", "lonlat", "name"]
}
```

Purposefully I have kept "size" to be very high, because my application requires all the data at once. Note that I am asking for only 4 fields.

The format of output is a json array in the result object.

```
    [{
          "_index" : "gequest",
          "_type" : "airports",
          "_id" : "ZYTL",
          "_score" : 1.0,
          "fields" : {
            "lonlat" : [ "121.5390015", "38.96569824" ],
            "icao" : [ "ZYTL" ],
            "name" : [ "Zhoushuizi Airport" ],
            "city" : [ "Dalian" ]
          }
    }

    ...
    ]
```

I am looking for a way to **avoid meta-data repeating as part of each document, i.e. index, type, id and score** . I know which index and type I am querying to which confuses me why result is giving out these obvious details, and for a non-lucune-type-query why score is relevant? If I remove the query clause, I still get the _score in the result.

Comment: "Metadata fields are always returned as scalars." from their website

Comment: This may help https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-arrayformat

Comment: hi master mind, I tried this plugin. Installed on E-1.4.5, but getting empty array.